# Ubuntu Server changing Monitor from DVI to VGA

Tags: server, monitor, vga, dvi

i have a little problem with my Ubuntu Server 12.04. I installed it yesterday with a DVI monitor connected. With the DVI Monitor, everything works fine. But when I try to connect it with an other monitor over VGA, nothing will be displayed and the server seems to stop at boot (can't connect over ssh). I searched the web already but I can't find a solution for my problem.

So my question is: Is there a possibility to change the main video output to VGA?

My Videocard: NVidia 9800gt

Comment: So, your card has a DVI and a VGA output? Or are you using a VGA output from another source, ie: motherboard?

Comment: Yes my card has both and nope, the only output I am using is the DVI source right now. When I unplug the DVI cable and plug the VGA in, the BIOS is shown correctly, but as soon as the GRUB loader should appear, nothing happens.

Comment: What happens if you boot without anything connected and plug in the monitor the to dvi connector? can you check when it halts on the boot?

Comment: Ok, so if I boot without anything connected, I can connect to it via SSH. And when I plug the DVI cable in while running, everything works fine. But when I plug the VGA cable in while running, it somehow works but the text is completely messed up and some errors are shown.

Comment: Now I tried to connect the VGA Monitor over a DVI adapter and it works perfectly.